# Horizontal listView inside Vertical Listview in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qt4

I want to make an horizontal listView works as a delegate for another veritcal listView, I've wrote the following code:

```
import Qt 4.7

Item {
    id:main
    width: 360
    height: 640

    Component{
        id:myDelegate
            ListView{
                id:list2
                spacing: 5
                width:list.width
                height:list.height/3
                interactive: true
                orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                model: ListModel {
                    ListElement {
                        name: "Bill Smith"
                        number: "555 3264"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        name: "John Brown"
                        number: "555 8426"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        name: "Sam Wise"
                        number: "555 0473"
                    }

                    ListElement {
                        name: "Sam Wise"
                        number: "555 0473"
                    }

                    ListElement {
                        name: "Sam Wise"
                        number: "555 0473"
                    }
                }
                delegate: Text{text:name
                width: main.width/3}

                focus: true
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill:  parent
                    onClicked: {
                        ListView.list2.currentIndex = ListView.list2.indexAt(mouseX, mouseY)
                    }
                }

            }
    }

    ListView {
        id: list
        clip: true
        spacing: 5
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: ListView.Vertical
        model: Model{}
        delegate:myDelegate

//        highlight: Rectangle {
//            width: list.currentItem.width
//            color: "lightsteelblue"
//            radius: 5
//        }
        focus: true
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill:  parent
            onClicked: {
                list.currentIndex = list.indexAt(mouseX, mouseY)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The vertical listview scroll well but the horizontal one does not scroll.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried it once and it didn't work, the outer list handles all events. The solution was to have a Flickable additionally to the ListViews and anchor the contentX of the horizontal and contentY of the vertical lists to contentX and contentY of the Flickable.

Some semi complete code to show the principle:

```
Item {

    ListView {

        anchors.fill: parent
        clip: true
        orientation: ListView.Vertical
        interactive: false
        contentY: listController.contentY
        delegate: ListView {
             orientation: ListView.Horizontal
             interactive: false
             contentX: listController.contentX
        }

    }

    Flickable {
        id: listController
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentHeight: vert.contentHeight
        contentWidth: horizontalElement.width
    }

}
```

Comment: That is right
Another solution was to remove the focus:true from the vertical list

Answer (score 6):

I tried this solution on the simulator and it worked.

```
import QtQuick 1.1
import com.nokia.symbian 1.1

Page {
    id: mainPage
    anchors.fill: parent


    ListModel {
        id: colorsModel
        ListElement {
            colorCode: "red"
        }
        ListElement {
            colorCode: "green"
        }
        ListElement {
            colorCode: "blue"
        }
        ListElement {
            colorCode: "orange"
        }
        ListElement {
            colorCode: "white"
        }
        ListElement {
            colorCode: "purple"
        }
        ListElement {
            colorCode: "gray"
        }
        ListElement {
            colorCode: "yellow"
        }
        ListElement {
            colorCode: "purple"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 30
        spacing: 20
        cacheBuffer: 200 // in pixels

        delegate:
            ListView {
            width: parent.width;
            height: 50;

            spacing: 20
            model: colorsModel
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal
            delegate:
                Rectangle {
                color: colorCode
                width: 50
                height: 50

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        console.log(colorCode + " clicked");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `MouseArea` in your vertical list view which steals all events to your horizontal ListView. Best practice in QML is to include all `MouseArea` components inside the delegate.

Also, instead of using the `indexAt(mouseX,mouseY)` method, use the `index` property available to all delegates.

In order to propogate the mouse event from list delegate's `MouseArea` to list2 delegate's `MouseArea`, use `mouse.accepted = false`

```
Item {
    id:main
    width: 360
    height: 640

    Component{
        id:myDelegate
            ListView{
                id:list2
                spacing: 5
                width:list.width
                height:list.height/3
                interactive: true
                orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                model: ListModel {
                    ListElement {
                        name: "Bill Smith"
                        number: "555 3264"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        name: "John Brown"
                        number: "555 8426"
                    }
                    ListElement {
                        name: "Sam Wise"
                        number: "555 0473"
                    }

                    ListElement {
                        name: "Sam Wise"
                        number: "555 0473"
                    }

                    ListElement {
                        name: "Sam Wise"
                        number: "555 0473"
                    }
                }
                delegate: Text {
                text:name
                width: main.width/3}

                focus: true
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill:  parent
                    onClicked: {
                        list2.currentIndex = index;
                    }
                }

              }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill:  parent
            onClicked: {
                list2.ListView.view.currentIndex = index;
                mouse.accepted = false;
            }
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: list
        clip: true
        spacing: 5
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: ListView.Vertical
        model: Model{}
        delegate:myDelegate
        focus: true
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, is there a solution to set a ListModel (from cpp) for each inner listview?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `z` property to make outer lists handle mouse events first.

```
ListView {
    z: 100 // put whatever you want or need
    delegate: ListView {
        z: 1000 // put whatever is above 100
    }
}
```

Or even better:

```
ListView {
    delegate: ListView {
        z: parent.z + 1        
    }
}
```

Not quite sure this is a reliable and proper way though.